# Cannot acess application created with Python scripting extension of GeoServer?

Tags: python, geoserver

I am trying to use the python scripting extension of Geoserver version 2.13.0 to create an application.

I installed the extension by following this tutorial: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/scripting/installation.html

I created a new script from menu >scripts >add new script

[image]

The code I am using :

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello World!']
```

My problem is when I try to access the application from the link 
`ip-address/script/apps/name_application` I get the 404 error.

Also when I go to the link ip-address/script/apps I get:

```
{"scripts": ["name_application"]}
```

I am following this tutorial: 
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/scripting/hooks.html

Is there anything I am missing here?

A link to Geoserver log file: https://pastebin.com/DfyUJfAc

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Ironically, your link to the [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.13.0/user/community/scripting/) returns a 404 error.

Comment: I apologize I don't know why the link stopped working, I edited it.